# Recursive function call - Python

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, recursion

I have a list of integers larger than zero. I need to identify the one with the highest number of dividers. For this I created two functions: one that gives me all the divisors of all the elements of a list and another that filters which element that has more divisors. The problem is that I can not make the maisDivisores function directly receive a list of only the elements (without dividers), you know? If I call the function 1 (listaDivisores) within the function 2 (maisDivisores) always crashes. However if I call manually, it works good. I've tried all the possibilities and nothing. How do I call the first function in the second for this to work getting the gross list?

```
def listaDivisores(lista):
    if lista == []:
        return []
    else:
        lista=qs(lista)
        resultado=[]
        resultado.append((lista[0],[y for y in range(1,((lista[0])+1)) if (int(lista[0]))%y==0]))
        return resultado+listaDivisores(lista[1:])
    return listaDivisores(lista)


def maisDivisores(lista):

    if len(lista)==[]:
        return "Nenhum número."

    else:
        **lista=listaDivisores(lista)**
        if int(len(lista))==1:
            return lista[0]
        elif int(len(lista[0][1]))<int(len(lista[1][1])):
            lista.pop(0)
        elif int(len(lista[0][1]))==int(len(lista[1][1])):
            if lista[0]<lista[1]:
                lista.pop(0)
            else:
                lista.pop(1)
        else:
            lista.pop(1)
        return maisDivisores(lista)
    return lista
```

[functions working separately; error log when working together.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVktP.png)

Comment: any reason to use recursion??

Comment: SORTED OUT!! Deletes the first function. I did one. Hence I did ... gross list caught the first element in a destructive way. With an understanding of the list, create a list of divisors it, if the list is different from empty enter the new function to get all the elements then she will give me a list of divisors of all. then you can compare and return me the element that has the largest number of divisors

Comment: Recursion is demanding the teacher to solve the problem.

Comment: I see, I suppose that should have guess it...

Comment: in that case I recommend using tail recursion, oh and you don't need to use `int(len(...))` because `len(...)` already return a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily get the divisor of a number with list comprehension like this

```
def divisores(n):
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be positive")
    return [x for x in range(1,n+1) if n%x==0 ]
```

then you can use the build in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a `key` function to get the desire result

```
>>> test=[24, 5, 9, 42] 
>>> max( test, key=lambda x:len(divisores(x)))
24
>>>
```

if you also want to get the divisor in the same step, you can use a generator or list comprehension to build a intermediary result from which get the max

for example

```
>>> max( ( (x,divisores(x)) for x in test), key=lambda y:len(y[1]))
(24, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24])
```

here `( (x,divisores(x)) for x in test)` is the generator, which create a tuple with the number and the list of its divisors

or

```
>>> test2 = [ (x,divisores(x)) for x in test ]
>>> test2
[(24, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24]), (5, [1, 5]), (9, [1, 3, 9]), (42, [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42])]
>>> max(test2,key=lambda x:len(x[1]))
(24, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24])
>>>
```

and any of those can be made into a simple function.

Your implementation is just too convoluted for what you want and frankly I have a hard time understanding it

Comment: Thanks man! It became much easier. I forgot to mention we could not use functions such as max, min, sum, etc., but could implement another to replace the max. Thank you very much!! You saved me